# Errors when running Eclipse on Java 17

Tags: java, eclipse, java-17

I get errors when I try to start Eclipse 2021-06 (4.20.0) on a Java 17 JRE.

The errors show in a dialog and the *Error Log*:

[image: Screen shot]

How can I fix this?

The contents of the error messages is this:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2bc378f7
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.overrideLoadResult(ModuleClassLoader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.endParse(Parser.java:11750)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12949)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:11521)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:846)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2bc378f7
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.overrideLoadResult(ModuleClassLoader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.endParse(Parser.java:11750)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12949)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:11521)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:846)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.Authenticator java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @1ab8b487
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.config.configtypes.RemoteConfigurationType$RemoteConfigAuthenticator.getDefault(RemoteConfigurationType.java:376)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.config.configtypes.RemoteConfigurationType.getCheckstyleConfiguration(RemoteConfigurationType.java:99)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.config.CheckConfiguration.getCheckstyleConfiguration(CheckConfiguration.java:161)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckerFactory.getCacheKey(CheckerFactory.java:157)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckerFactory.createChecker(CheckerFactory.java:99)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.Auditor.runAudit(Auditor.java:139)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckstyleBuilder.handleBuildSelection(CheckstyleBuilder.java:307)
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.core.builder.CheckstyleBuilder.build(CheckstyleBuilder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:846)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: That release is older than Java 17, I'm not very surprised that there are issues. Why not just run it with an earlier Java version? 4.21 added support for Java 17, so there's a chance that it also runs on 17.

Comment: Maybe that is what I have to do. As an alternative solution I'm experimenting with `--add-opens` in `eclipse.ini`, but I don't seem to get it to work...

Comment: The bug reports on Eclipse Bugzilla suggest this is caused by Lombok - do you have that installed?

Comment: @greg-449: Yes, I have! Good tip! I'll try removing it!

Comment: @greg-449: Removing Lombok integration from Eclipse does indeed get rid of the problem with JDT. I still get an error from the Checkstyle plugin, though. Anyway, it doesn't seem to be Eclipse itself that is the problem in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problems turned out to be caused by the Eclipse plugins that I was using, not Eclipse itself.

The plugins are these:

- Lombok 1.18.20.
- Eclipse Checkstyle 8.36.1

The solution for me is to run Eclipse using an older JRE.

#### Cause

The problems are caused by the fact that the plugins make use of internal JDK components that never were intended to be exposed. They have been encapsulated in the lasted JDK as part of this change:

https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403

#### Update: Fixes

- Eclipse Checkstyle claims to have fixed the problem in this ticket (I have not verified): https://github.com/checkstyle/eclipse-cs/issues/281
- Lombok claims to have fixed the problem in this ticket (I have not verified): https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2810

I welcome other solutions that make it possible to continue running Eclipse with the same old plugins even on Java 17!

Comment: Another demonstration how the way that Lombok works is notoriously unstable. It puts its claws deeply into the compiler and/or runtime to be allowed to do its magic. While I appreciate the feature set it provides (at least parts of it), it does come at a significant cost. In this case you'll probably just have to wait for an updated Lombok plugin.

Comment: The errors are presumably because of [JEP 403: Strongly Encapsulate JDK Internals](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403) making it harder for things to mess around with internals

Comment: @greg-449: Yupp. I tried to handle the problems by adding `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` to `eclipse.ini`, but I didn't get it to work. It would be great if someone investigated how to do that! (I can't spend time on it right now, unfortunately.)